# Read and parse string line by line in a file - data source file data not in sequence or in-pattern for data append

Tags: python, parsing, dictionary

This question is to clarify an issue I have when dealing with string in a file source and appending it to a dictionary key list, extended from another SO question. This is a sample source file below :

```
 Name: David
 Age: 23
 Name: Ally
 Age: 21
 Age: 20
 Name: John
 Name: Peter
 Age: 22
```

If you noticed the file have name,age,name,age and suddenly age, name and back to name,age... This could happen (twisted between name and age) to any lines in the file.

If everything start with name and end with age; then I can read and parse it one by one onto list of dictionary with this code :

```
file = open("file")
data = file.readlines()
data = [i.strip() for i in data]
dict_ = {"Person":[]}
for i in range(0,len(data),2):
    line = data[i].split(':')
    nxt_line = data[i+1].split(':')
    dict_['Person'].append({'Name':line[1], 'Age': nxt_line[1]})
```

The problem is when some of the line of name and age twisted in data file as example of data file above and when run the code the value is wrongly parse.

How to ensure the value of name and age can be correctly passed to dictionary even if the position of name and age in the source file is upside down and does not follow the sequence.

Please advise. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
file = open("temp2.txt")
data = file.readlines()
data = [i.strip() for i in data]
dict_ = {"Person":[]}
for i in range(0,len(data),2):
    line = data[i].split(':')[1].strip()  # Remove the leading spaces of the second split item
    nxt_line = data[i+1].split(':')[1].strip()  # Remove the leading spaces of the second split item in the next line
    if line.isnumeric():  # 'any_int'.isnumeric() returns True
        dict_['Person'].append({'Name':nxt_line, 'Age': line})
    else:  # If the string is not numeric type, it must be the name
        dict_['Person'].append({'Name':line, 'Age': nxt_line})
```

**OUTPUT** :

```
{'Person': [{'Name': 'David', 'Age': '23'}, {'Name': 'Ally', 'Age': '21'}, {'Name': 'John', 'Age': '20'}, {'Name': 'Peter', 'Age': '22'}]}
```

Comment: Hi sir, I have test this method, almost the same as what your present before. But I need to understand correctly what does it mean (1)data = [i.strip() for i in data]. I know strip() remove character and space...please correct me. Thank you.

Comment: After `data = file.readlines()`, the list items would have `\n` in the end. We use `.strip()` method to get rid of them. `.strip()` method, in general, removes leading and trailing whitespaces from strings.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to pair every two lines.

**Ex:**

```
with open(filename) as infile:
    data = [i.strip() for i in infile.readlines()]

data = [data[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(data), 2)]    #Divide line to chunks of 2. 
result = []
for m, n in data:
    val = dict([m.split(":")])
    val.update(dict([n.split(":")]))
    result.append(val)    
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'Age': ' 23', 'Name': ' David'},
 {'Age': ' 21', 'Name': ' Ally'},
 {'Age': ' 20', 'Name': ' John'},
 {'Age': ' 22', 'Name': ' Peter'}]
```

Comment: Hi sir...this work and have tested it..thank you for your support and kind attention. One of the solution that can be applied.